# Passing data between different speed loops in LabVIEW

Tags: labview

I have a (desktop) LabVIEW program running several large While loops. Each loop corresponds to the functions on an IO card in a myRIO DAQ system. Each card operates at a different speed, therefore each loop and subVIs in my code run at different speeds as well.

However, I'm now finding that I need to pass data from a low speed loop to a high speed loop, and I'm not sure how to best go about it.

The low speed loop actually connects via TCP to a Yokogowa power analyzer, and the loop speed is 50ms (20Hz). The high speed loop runs at 50kHz, and performs math operations using inputs from a high speed ADC to calculate motor torque, and needs the info from the low speed loop (power analyzer) to proceed. There's an 816:1 data flow difference.

At runtime, it appears to work fine, until I spin the motor up, then the overtorque routine kicks in and shuts me down.

So I next tried to queue the data, and that only significantly slowed the high speed loop.

That being said, my thought was to take the incoming data on the low speed loop, and fill an array with that data (816 deep) and queue it up to the high speed loop, but I'm not quite certain how to go about that as well.

How should I accomplish what I'm trying to do in a more efficient and proper manner?

Comment: *The high speed loop runs at 50kHz* - are you sure? On a desktop OS? If you need this kind of speed and you have a myRIO I think you'd be much better off running this task in the real-time OS on the myRIO.

Answer (score 2):

Look to the [Real-Time FIFO](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370622L-01/lvrtvihelp/rtfifovipal/) palette. The functions here create and operate a lockless-FIFO system explicitly designed for passing data in a deterministic way between loops. Used correctly, they guarantee that the slower loop, trying to write data, will not lock the FFO in a way that throws the faster loop off of its schedule.

You can find a simple example of the RT FIFO code [here](https://forums.ni.com/t5/Example-Programs/Simple-Real-Time-FIFO-Example-for-LabVIEW/ta-p/3507189). You'll find more in the LabVIEW shipping examples.

Comment: I think the best reference for this would be the cRIO developers' guide: http://www.ni.com/pdf/products/us/fullcriodevguide.pdf (start on page 29). As far as I'm aware the same info applies to myRIO as to cRIO.

Comment: @Jedi post an image. Abstractly, all the comments from multiple commenters point toward the FIFO solution, so, concretely, issue must be in your particular code (or you described situation in say we’ve misunderstood). Did you put a timeout of 0 on the dequeue since your HS loop is going to keep the structure mostly emoty?

Comment: From the cRIO dev guide I linked to, the appropriate mechanism for the OP's requirement on a Real-Time system would appear to be the snappily titled *Single-Process Shared Variable with RT FIFO Enabled (single-element)*. However OP has clarified that this is actually on desktop LabVIEW.

Answer (score 2):

If the high speed loop is running faster then it only really needs the latest value so you need a variable/tag type communication.

Depending on what you are aware of already there are a few options:

- Local/Global Variable
- Functional Global Variable (but globals are faster)
- Notifier (if you use get staus you can read this like a variable.

I would pick one you are comfortable with and try that.

Comment: This is good general advice for desktop LabVIEW (hence upvoted) but since the question relates to LabVIEW Real-Time, @srm's answer is better for the specific case.

Comment: I see what you mean but a FIFO wont work since you reading faster than you write. 

You could use the RT FIFO for determinism with a zero timeout and then you have to store the last value locally in case it has not been written since the last read.

Comment: @nekomatic I'm doing this in a desktop app, not the myRio FPGA or embedded system....

Comment: @jamesmc86 - will the higher speed loop continue operations on whatever value is present in the global variable until it changes? I'm just trying to make sure that this is the case, I can handle the data if so.

Comment: @JediEngineer OK, if this is just on desktop then any of these is fine; I would probably use a notifier and read it with `Get Notifier Status`.

Comment: LabVIEW has channels now, the tag channel would be perfect for this.

Comment: @JediEngineer Yep the variables or notifier will just keep returning the last value written (the tag channel also has the same behaviour).